# Torque BankFailure (cannot debit job account)

Tags: pbs, torque

I am new with torque scheduler and I try to understand checkjob command result : `BankFailure  (cannot debit job account)`.

It concerns a job marked "Q" and appear to be stuck

When I type `checkjob [job_id]` I get this message:

```
State: Idle  EState: Deferred
Creds:  user:xxx  group:xxx  class:batch  qos:DEFAULT
WallTime: 00:00:00 of 12:00:00
SubmitTime: Wed Jun  1 13:37:41
(Time Queued  Total: 2:49:31  Eligible: 00:00:00)

StartDate: -2:49:29  Wed Jun  1 13:37:43
Total Tasks: 1

Req[0]  TaskCount: 1  Partition: DEFAULT
Network: [NONE]  Memory >= 0  Disk >= 0  Swap >= 0
Opsys: [NONE]  Arch: [NONE]  Features: [xxxxx]

IWD: [NONE]  Executable:  [NONE]
Bypass: 0  StartCount: 4
PartitionMask: [ALL]
Flags:       RESTARTABLE

job is deferred.  Reason:  BankFailure  (cannot debit job account)
Holds:    Defer  (hold reason:  BankFailure)
PE:  1.00  StartPriority:  40
cannot select job xxxx for partition DEFAULT (job hold active)
```

According to the torque official doc, `BankFailure  (cannot debit job account)` mean "*If instead, you see the following as part of the checkjob output, it means that the job you are trying to run will exceed the allocation you have remaining. This may simply be because you did not specify a walltime as part of your job specification.*"

But the walltime value is set, and there is enough core to run this job.

Does It means that walltime is not enough to run this job ? Or Does It mean that time calculation allowed to the user is higher than his quota.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It looks like this message comes from Gold accounting and allocation management system developed at PNNL that currently exists as an open source project hosted by Adaptive Computing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't a Torque problem. "BankFailure" isn't in the Torque source, and it's very likely qrun on this job would succeed. I would focus on examining your accounting manager configuration (e.g., make sure funds have been allocated for the appropriate credential).

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! yes the pb come from gold and allocation fund process. The user didn't have enought "time calculation credit"to run job.
I add some funds to this user and the job started !